# Javascript: Get first number substring for each semi-colon separated substring

Tags: javascript, string, for-loop

I am creating a script of time calculation from MySQL as I don't want to load the scripts on server-side with PHP.

I am getting the data and parsing it using JSON, which gives me a string of values for column and row data. The format of this data looks like:

> 1548145153,1548145165,End,Day;1548145209,1548145215,End,Day;1548148072,1548148086,End,Day;1548161279,1548161294,End,Day;1548145161,1548145163,End,Day;1548148082,1548148083,End,Day;1548161291,1548161293,End,Day

I need to split this string by semi-colon, and then extract the first `VARCHAR` number from before each comma to use that in subsequent calculation.

So for example, I would like to extract the following from the data above:

`[1548145153, 1548145209, 1548148072, 1548161279, 1548145161, 1548148082, 1548161291]`

I used the following type of for-loop but is not working as I wanted to:

```
for (var i=0; i < words.length; i++) {
           var1 = words[i];
           console.log(var1);
}
```

The string and the for-loop together are like following:

```
var processData = function(data) {
for(var a = 0; a < data.length; a++) {

     var obj = data[a];
     var str= obj.report // something like 1548145153,1548145165,End,Day;1548145209,1548145215,End,Day;1548148072,1548148086,End,Day;1548161279,1548161294,End,Day;1548145161,1548145163,End,Day;1548148082,1548148083,End,Day;1548161291,1548161293,End,Day
     words = str.split(',');
     words = str.split(';');
     for (var i=0; i < words.length; i++) {
           var1 = words[i];
           var2 = var1[0];
           console.log(var2);
}
```

Comment: Why dont you just use the data in an array? It is not managable to put all strints in different variables.

You can access any item in variable "words" easily by refering the index.

console.log(words[0]) will print the first item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach based on a regular expression:

```js
const str = "1548145153,1548145165,End,Day;1548145209,1548145215,End,Day;1548148072,1548148086,End,Day;1548161279,1548161294,End,Day;1548145161,1548145163,End,Day;1548148082,1548148083,End,Day;1548161291,1548161293,End,Day";

const ids = str.match(/(?<=;)(\d+)|(^\d+(?=,))/gi)

console.log(ids)
```

The general idea here is to classify the first `VARCHAR` value as either:

- a number sequence directly preceded by a `;` character (see 1 below) or, for the edge case
- the very first number sequence of the input string directly followed by a `,` character (see 2 below).

These two cases are expressed as follows:

1. Match any number sequence that is preceded by a `;` using the [negated lookbehind rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_special_characters): `(?<=;)(\d+)`, where `;` is the character that must follow a number sequence `\d+` to be a match
2. Match any number sequence that is the first number sequence of the input string, and that has a `,` directly following it using the [lookahead rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_special_characters) `(^\d+(?=,))`, where `\d+` is the number sequence and `,` is the character that must directly follow that number sequence to be a match
3. These building blocks 1 and 2 are combined using the `|` operator to achieve the final result

Answer (score 1):

First thing is that you override `words` with the content of `str.split(';')`, so it won't hold what you expect. To split the string into chunks, split by `;` first, then iterate over the resulting array and within the loop, split by `,`.

```js
const str= "1548145153,1548145165,End,Day;1548145209,1548145215,End,Day;1548148072,1548148086,End,Day;1548161279,1548161294,End,Day;1548145161,1548145163,End,Day;1548148082,1548148083,End,Day;1548161291,1548161293,End,Day";

const lines = str.split(';');

lines.forEach(line => {
  const parts = line.split(',');
  console.log(parts[0]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is not correct, you'll have to separate strings twice as there are two separators. i.e. a comma and a semicolon.

I think you need a nested loop for that.

```
var str = "1548145153,1548145165,End,Day;1548145209,1548145215,End,Day;1548148072,1548148086,End,Day;1548161279,1548161294,End,Day;1548145161,1548145163,End,Day;1548148082,1548148083,End,Day;1548161291,1548161293,End,Day"
let words = str.split(';');
for (var i=0; i < words.length; i++) {
    let varChars = words[i].split(',');
    for (var j=0; j < varChars.length; i++)
        console.log(varChars[j]);
}
```

I hope this helps. Please don't forget to mark the answer.